# How to change styles in Table Pagination Material-ui v.5.15 with React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pagination

Expected Behaviour :[Expected Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXYZ2.png)
But I'm getting : [My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9iMX.png)
I'm not sure why it is happening !

```js
import TablePagination from '@mui/material/TablePagination';

const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);

const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        setPage(0);
    };

<TablePagination
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 20]}
    component="div"
    count={filteredData.length}
    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
    page={page}
    onPageChange={handleChangePage}
    onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}

/>
```